# Is it unsafe to list the env/config variables in the UI?

Tags: api, security, https, configuration

I have an application that during the boot time

1. Collects different configurations from different services
2. Merges the configs into one config
3. Uses the config

It also has a read-only config UI for showing the configurations to the admins only. The UI masks the sensitive values and serves the configs over HTTPS.

The question: Is this considered a security vulnerability? If yes, on a scale of 1 to 10, how serious is it?

Answer (score 0):

The trickier part is securely downloading and merging them, maintaining authenticity, integrity, avoiding logic flaws (eg. what if a critical piece is unavailable), preparing for a range of threats one could think of (eg. how much you want to trust the sources, how configuration should be protected there and so on). Then displaying the end result with sensitive fields masked to privileged users sounds ok, and a lot easier.